# Telerik control progress bar

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I'm trying my question here since Telerik's site takes about 3 days, plus I just like this site better. I'm trying to read the value of the RadProgressBar. I fail early since I cannot get a reference to the progress bar ID="pbrNewBid". I click a button and this code runs. It is within the document.ready function.
The error occurs on the findProgressBar line. It says you can't get the value of a null reference. I tried every permutation :-(
I forgot to mention, it's in an asp.net using a single master page and a default.aspx content page.

```
$("#b1").click(function () {
    var parent = $("#<%=pbrOpenBid.ClientID%>").parent();
    var val = $telerik.findProgressBar("pbrOpenBid", parent).get_value();
    alert("value=" + val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Sys.Application.Load event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383829.aspx) for IScriptControls like the Telerik AJAX controls. In earlier events their objects are not created yet.

Here is an example:

```
<telerik:RadProgressBar runat="server" ID="pbrNewBid" Value="12"></telerik:RadProgressBar>
<script>
    function getProgressBarValue() {
        var pb = $find("<%=pbrNewBid.ClientID%>");
        alert(pb.get_value());

        Sys.Application.remove_load(getProgressBarValue);//remove the handler so it executes only once, otherwise AJAX responses will call it again
    }
    Sys.Application.add_load(getProgressBarValue);
</script>
```